# Closed-form solution of a linear time-varying system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, dynamical-systems, closed-form, control-theory

Consider the following three-dimensional linear time-varying system
$$\label{eq1}\tag{$\star$}
\dot{x}(t)=(A \cos(\omega_1 t) + B \cos(\omega_2 t) )x(t), \ \ x(0)\in\mathbb{R}^{3},
$$
where $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are positive real numbers **such that $\omega_1\ne \omega_2$** and
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}a & -a & 0 \\ -a & a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \quad B=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -b & b \\ 0 & b & -b\end{bmatrix}
$$
with $a,b$ positive real numbers. Notice that $A$, $B$ **do not** commute. However, the commutator
$$
[A,B]=AB-BA = \begin{bmatrix}0 & ab & -ab \\ -ab & 0 & ab \\ ab & -ab & 0\end{bmatrix}
$$
is a skew-symmetric matrix (I don't know if this can be useful though).

> **My questions are:**
>
> 1. Does there exist an explicit closed-form expression for the solution of \eqref{eq1}?
> 2. If not, is it possible to find a bound on $\|x(t)\|$ which explicitly depends on $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$?

I've been stuck on this problem for a while now. So I would greatly appreciate any kind of comment or help. Thanks.

Comment: You may find this useful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770679/how-to-compute-time-ordered-exponential

Comment: Is $\omega_1/\omega_2$ rational?

Comment: Why do you think the bound should depend on $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$. It is more likely that it will depend on $x_0$. Have you simulated the system to get some insight into the behaviour?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen: If assuming $\omega_1/\omega_2$ rational simplifies the problem, then yes, we can make this assumption.

Comment: @MrYouMath: Yes, I've run some simulations. The behavior is not very clear though. It seems that as $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ grow, the trajectories are bounded and closer to zero.

Comment: If it is rational means that the it is periodic. So if you can obtain the state transition matrix for one period, either obtained numerically or analytically, then you look at the eigenvalues, which should lie inside the unit circle to be stable.